# What are 5 new syntaxes for declaring a function template?

Tags: c++, c++-concepts

[This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zQ9tT8fbtSo#t=48m30s) video specifies some problems with current TS version of concepts, and one of them is:

> 5 new syntaxes for declaring a function template

without examples given. 
So my question is what are they?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given the trivial concept definition:

```
template <class T> concept bool C = true;
```

We can declare the same function template `f` as:

```
template <class T> requires C<T> void f(T);
template <class T> void f(T) requires C<T>;
template <C T> void f(T); // colloquially known as "terse" syntax
C{T} void f(T); // template introduction syntax
void f(C); // abbreviated function template syntax
```

Comment: I understand all 5 examples, but what does template <class T> concept bool C = true; mean?

Comment: Is it variable template? Aka the simplest concept ever: for every type it is true?

Comment: That is the definition of a variable concept `C` with one type parameter that is always satisfied.